# Could I recover my list from suddenly vanished GO Note android widget?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I've Samsung S3 (GT-I9300) with Omega v60 ROM (Android 4.3) and Boeffla Kernal 5.8 (3.0.101).

I was using SuperSU and in the one of it's updates, it messed with the ROOT so my device now went from ROOTED to NON-ROOTED.

My device was working normally today, and sometimes when it's loaded, the phone feels like it restarted when actually it didn't restart, and Boeffla notification says that I'm missing root which is obvious for sure.

I didn't wait for the phone to finish it's frozen status and make this restart-like thing, so I forced restart it by long-pressing the power button.

The device was stuck at the loading screen for two times until I removed the battery for like 5 minutes and then re-inserted it and powered on the phone to see that it's behaving like I've installed a new fresh ROM.

I had a long list of To-do in my GO Note widget and now I'm not able to recover this list.

Is there any way to restore the GO Note widget list ?

I was thinking that since I did't format or anything, I may access that list in a form of RAW data.

When I try to add an account as maybe I had cloud backup or something, it gives me an 403 error with disallowed_useragent error so maybe I can work my way from there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is dedicated for code related problems. I don't think the community here deals with problems with the Android Device itself.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but I'm asking developers here if I could reach that list in a RAW form or something so that will require a developer more than a novice user.